# Is there a way to set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider throughout my computer so I dont have to add it to every script I run?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, openssl, node-modules

I updated my Node to v18.16.1 and now when I run a script in vue I get the following error:
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.16.1

I have a work around that works to add "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider &&" in front of the script, But is there something I can do that goes on the computer so I dont have to add this to every single script I have?

Ive looked into openSSL which is interesting at best. Looking for what people have done for the long term workaround to not need to add something every time.

Comment: Likely set it as OS environment variable in a way that is possible for your OS, which seems to be Windows?

Comment: have you ever tried "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
" in linux?